# Going back in Fragments by pressing the back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I want to go back to another fragment by pressing the back button. I already read, that the `addToBackStack (String tag)` should help but it didn't really work.

Here is what I'm doing when switching fragments.

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, new MainFragment());
ft.addToBackStack("Mainfragment");
ft.commit();
```

So now, the Fragment opens, and starts an `AsyncTask` where a loading circle appears. After the loading the data gets displayed. When I now press the back button once, the fragment goes back to the start of the `AsyncTask` where the loading circle is created. But the `AsyncTask` doesn't continue. When I press the back button again, the app closes.

I tried to add `onBackPressed` but it just told me, that this won't work in a Fragment. What would be the best way to go here?

**Edit for clarification:**
There's no error. It's just not working. It is like I don't even have the line addToBackStack –

Comment: There's no error. It's just not working. It is like I don't even have the line `addToBackStack`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same situation before and I ended up with this solution. When you add or replace the Fragments, you need to add it to the backStack with a unique name. Then when the back button is pressed you can see which fragment was the active one with the method below inside the FragmentActivity that you created the Fragment.

```
private String getCurrentFragmentName() {

    int backStackEntryCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    String fragmentName;

    if (backStackEntryCount > 0) {
        fragmentName = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryAt(backStackEntryCount - 1).getName();
    } else {
        fragmentName = "";
    }

    return fragmentName;
}
```

and in on onKeyDown() method do the following.

```
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && getCurrentFragmentName().equals("your fragment name")) {
        // Handle back press for this case.
        return true;

    } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && getCurrentFragmentName().equals("your another fragment")) {

        // Handle back press for another Fragment
        return true;

    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

And this is the Place how I add the Fragment with backStack

```
transaction.addToBackStack("Your Fragment Name");
```