# Back button support in Android fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, back-stack

I'm working on an inherited Android project that makes use of fragments. The mainactivity has a side menu drawer that allows the user to tap on a list of items, each of which opens a new fragment in another file.

Right now, pressing the back button closes the app abruptly. I wish for the back button to work such that it will bring the user back to the previously viewed fragment, and when the user is at the very first viewed fragment, pressing a back button will bring an app exit confirmation box.

I understand that I should be using addToBackStack() but I'm not sure how to implement it in my code.

Here's the code originally in mainactivity when an item is selected:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
switch (position) {
case 0:
  if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame != null) {
    Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content_frame);
    fm.befineTransaction().remove(currentFragment).commit();
    fm.popBackStack(null, FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
  }
  Item0 item1Fragment = new Item0();
  fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, item0Fragment).commit();
  break;
```

case 1 onwards are identical, except Item0/item0Fragment references are replaced with their respective values.

I'm very new to fragments, but from what I can see, the code is first detecting if the activity has a frame for the fragment, and if so, it removes the current fragment, and completely clears the fragment back stack. It then creates a new fragment, and replaces the current fragment with the new one.

Here's my code currently after some changes, and it seems to work, except for a few problems which I'll describe after the code:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
switch (position) {
case 0:
  Item0 item1Fragment = new Item0();
  ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, item0Fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
  break;
```

The above modified code provides correct navigation, except:

1. When the I've gone back to the very first fragment, then a back button press removes that fragment and presents an empty fragment on screen, and the next back button press will close the app. The desired behavior would be that a back button press on the very first fragment will bring out a confirmation button to close the app.
2. When the items on the side menu are tapped and selected, I call mItemList.setItemChecked(position). How do I call update this when the back button is tapped so that the previous selection is selected?

Does anyone know how to make this work?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not recommended by the Android design guidelines. If you are using a navigation drawer, then the pages that you can visit from the drawer are seen as top-level navigation. If, inside a particular page, there are any buttons or clickable lists that take the user to a detailed view (non-top-level navigation) or something, the user should be able to use the back button to go back to the top-level page. Don't use the back button to go from a top-level page to the previous top-level page. 

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation.html

Comment: Also, take a look at this http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

Comment: OK, So for my case, my top level consists of item1Fragment, item2Fragment, etc. Within each fragment, I can navigate to sub-pages, the back button will bring me from 1 sub-page to the previous one. However, once I'm at the top level page again, where should the back button bring me? For example, if when I start my app, the top level page that appears is item1Fragment. I then navigate to item3Fragment, then sub-pages 1-3. When I'm at sub-page3, pressing back takes back back to sub-page2, subpage-1, then item3Fragment. Now that I'm at a top level page, where should the next back button bring me?

Comment: If I refer to Facebook as an example (not sure if they're following Android guidelines), but starting the app brings me to News Feed. If I navigate to other top level pages, such as Messages, then Nearby Places, then Events, pressing back at Events brings me straight back to News Feed. Is this the correct expected behavior according to Android design guidelines?

Comment: I was actually about to give the Facebook app as an example of poor design. It uses the back button to go back to the previous screen, no matter where you are in the navigation hierarchy. It confuses the user and gives a poor UX. The Facebook app is about the contrary of how the Android Design Guidelines would like apps to look and feel.

When you are at a top level page, the back button should close the app. In some cases it is a good idea to ask the user for confirmation, more info about this can be found here: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/confirming-acknowledging.html

Comment: Thanks. I would indeed like to have a confirmation screen. In fact for my case, because the user would have first logged in, I would like to have a logout confirmation screen. How would I implement this in code?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49040/discussion-between-mark-buikema-and-user1118764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you checked the developer.android ? Here is how they explain.
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html#back-fragments

Comment: I have, but they make use of getSupportFragmentManager(), which is from android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager rather than android.app.FragmentManager which I'm using.

Comment: @user1118764 Read it here carefully.
// Works with either the framework FragmentManager or the
// support package FragmentManager (getSupportFragmentManager).

Comment: They explained it with these comments right above the code.

Comment: then you can directly call `getFragmentManager()` instead of getSupportFragmentManager()...

Comment: Thanks. The code in the link is similar to the above modified code I've tried, except it's using add() and I'm using replace(). I tried using add and while the fragment name on the action bar seems to indicate that the fragment has changed, the content in my fragments is empty. Also, even when using replace(), after I've reached the very first fragment, pressing back would clear the content area, when the desired behavior would actually be an exit confirmation instead. How and when do I detect that I'm at the very first fragment, and override the back button to display an exit confirmation?

Comment: @user1118764 I answered a similar question in SOF before. You can take a look.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/20053355/1080954

Comment: But beside that I have sample project in my GitHub Repo, it's using fragments and it's a work around for TabActivity. Instead using Activity under the TabActivity it works with the Fragments. You can take a look and let me know If you don't understand any of the project. Here it is >> https://github.com/osayilgan/samples/tree/master/SampleApp

Comment: @user1118764 by the way, to understand if you are in the last fragment or not, You can name the Fragments when you add them to the back stack. Give them string names and Check if it the last one. Check out this link to get the Fragment from stack.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20052996/going-back-in-fragments-by-pressing-the-back-button/20053355#20053355